How can I get the odor of joint compound out of my house?
The drywall in my house has recently been finished and I've noticed that there are some bad smells in the house and my head's been hurting.

Drywall usually does not smell "bad".  The smell from mud should be gone in an hour or two.  The bad smell might be from something else, but bad does not really give us much to go on.  More description than bad will help.

Pretty much everything contains chemicals.  It's which chemicals that matters.

Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

If the drywall mud was contaminated, perhaps getting moldy, the vapors and smells may take a long time to dissipate.
However, even uncontaminated "good" drywall mud has a smell. The normal smell will go away when the mud thoroughly dries.
Since the internet has never perfected the remote smell API, you'll have to have some friends familiar with construction and with working noses (see COVID) come over and try to identify the smell. Hopefully they can tell you if they smell normal drywall mud, mold, or something else. Once the smells are identified, further or no action can be planned.
Meanwhile, open windows, put window or box fans in. get some air cross-flow going. If the mud is "good" with no contaminants, it will dry sooner with airflow. Note that high humidity may work against faster drying, but air flow will help get the smells out, so they don't concentrate as they would in a closed room.
A strategy for placing fans:

If the construction was all on one portion of the house, place fans in the windows on that side of the house blowing out. Open windows on the other portions of the house, and if possible put fans blowing in. The general pressure and airflow will be to the rooms with the mud, and the mud air will get pushed out.
If the mud was applied all over the house, then you merely have to pick one end of the house to blow out, and the other end to blow in. Put the in vs out direction the same direction as any wind is blowing outside, so the wind is helping the fans.

Regarding the headaches, you may need to live elsewhere, or get a gas mask if you must live in the house. A painter's mask may be good enough, or an industrial finisher's mask that might be used in a workplace may be better. See your doctor if the headaches won't go away.

I feel like the only answer here is “Open up your house.” If it’s still stinky after a day of breezing, you might have a bigger problem on your hands.
